# Finding the matrix for a mapping of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand how to find the matrix for a mapping from a vector space to that same vector space.

For example, how would I find the matrix for the map $D: V\rightarrow V$ where $D$ is the differentiation operator and $V$ is the space of complex functions on $\mathbb R$ of the form $p(t)e^{\lambda t}$, where $$v_j(t)=t^{j-1}e^{\lambda t}/(j-1)!$$ with $j=1,...,n$.
(The matrix for $D$ with respect to the basis $v_1,...,v_n$).

Is there a general procedure I can follow to find the matrix for a mapping with respect to a given basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General case**

If $D$ is your operator and $e_i,i\in I$ is your basis, then you try to express all the $De_i$ in your basis:

$$De_i=\sum_{j\in I}\alpha_{ij} e_j.$$

And these coefficients $\alpha_{ij}$ are exactly the entries of the matrix representing $D$ in this basis. How to find this decomposition on the right is another question. It is easy if you have an inner product for which $e_i$ is an orthonormal basis, i.e. $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=1$ if $i=j$, zero otherwise. Then

$$\alpha_{ij}= \langle De_i,e_j\rangle.$$

---

**Example**. For your example, compute $Dv_i$:

$$Dv_i=\left(\frac{t^{i-2}}{(i-2)!}+\frac{t^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}\right)e^{\lambda j}=v_{i-1}+v_i.$$

Use $v_{-1}=0$. We therefore have

$$\alpha_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&\text{for $i=j$ or $i=j+1$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Note that your basis does not span the whole space of complex functions $p(t)e^{\lambda t}$, since the space itself is of infinite dimension but you have only $n$ basis-vectors. I therefore assumed that we are talking about the spanned substace $V$. Anyway, your resulting $n\times n$-matrix looks like this:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1& & &  \\
 &1&1& &  \\
&&\ddots&\ddots& \\
 & & &1&1 \\
 & & & &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$